# Textbox, delete button [c#]

Tags: c#, string, text, textbox

to add new letter to textbox i use

```
Textbox.Text = Textbox.Text + " ";
```

adds space etc., its simple

but i didnt figured out how can i delete last line

for examp.

text of textbox is abcdefg

and when user clicks delete, text is "abcdef" then "adcde" etc.

how can i do this ?

i tried to search the web but i failed because i dont know how to search that such a thing ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String text = Textbox.Text;
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    Textbox.Text = text.Substring(0,text.Length-1);
```

Comment: Hello, i get 'string' does not contain a definition for 'isNullOrEmpty error. what to do ?

Comment: Türkiyeden olduğunu gördüm bir de Türkçe yazim dedim, şimdi googleda aradım biraz bu fonksiyon mu desem artık neyse kendim yazabileceğim gördüm ama net 3.0 ve üstünde zaten varmış ? program net 4.0 kullanıyor sorun nerde anlamadım.

Comment: oh i just noticed its not isnullor.. its Is... whatever, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
  TextBox.Text = TextBox.Text.Remove(str.Length - 1, 1);
```